# CSS responsive vertical scrollbar issue

Tags: css, responsive-design, scrollbar, media-queries

I'm currently playing with [bootstraps v2.3.2. media querys](http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/scaffolding.html#responsive) (I'm not using bootstraps grid, just those 4 media queries) to test them on mobile and tablet devices, and I notice that I keep getting a *horizontal scrollbar* and I don't understand why?

Basically I have one `div` and this CSS:

```
html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
    box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
    margin:0;
    /* height: 3000px; */  /* forced vertical scrollbar */
    height: 300px;
}

div{
    padding: 0 10px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: aqua;
    width: 980px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    height: 100%;
}

/* Large desktop */
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    div{
        background: red;
        width: 1200px;
    }
}

/* Portrait tablet to landscape and desktop */
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 979px) {
    div{
        background: yellow;
        width: 768px;
    }
}

/* Landscape phone to portrait tablet */
@media (max-width: 767px) {
    div{
        background: blue;
        width: 100%;
    }
}

/* Landscape phones and down */
@media (max-width: 480px) {
    div{
        background: green;
    }
}
```

---

Situation when I force vertical scrollbar: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/veracelawo/1/edit?output)

But when I don't force vertical scrollbar, I get the wanted result: [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/wolelahifu/1/edit?output)

---

So it's obviously due the vertical scrollbar. I found this [article](http://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/) about scrollbar issue in Responsive Web Design, but I get the same result in both Chrome and FF.

---

**Update**: as looking the source of [bootstrap v3.3.2](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap) I've noticed that they have new media queries, however, they don't use the **minimal possible width** for the `.container`. This are their media queries:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 750px; /* 18px difference */
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 970px; /* 22px difference */
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1170px; /* 30px difference */
    }
}
```

And here's the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/yobuquwile/1/edit?output). Even when I forced the vertical scrollbar to appear, this won't trigger the horizontal scrollbar.

But if I want to use the **minimal possible width** for the media queries, like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
    .container {
        width: 768px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .container {
        width: 992px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
    .container {
        width: 1200px;
    }
}
```

This will trigger the `horizontal scrollbar` - [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/pamowidona/1/edit?output)

Did the guys from bootstrap did that on purpose, because of the possibly that there can be the presence of vertical scrollbar?

---

**Question**: Why can't I use the **minimal possible width** in the media query when the vertical scrollbar is present?

I know that this may be a novice question, but I would appreciate if someone clarify this for me.

Comment: The scrollbars, like you say, would seem to be the problem. The scrollbars reduce the width of the client area.

Comment: @w3d I've updated the question, but yes, the `scrollbar` seems to be the problem.

Comment: @w3d this is not the case on mobile chrome as far as i can tell. I know some desktop browsers do this.

Comment: @Persijn To be honest, I don't think I was properly awake when I first looked at this question. I checked it on a couple of _desktop_ browsers at the time and noticed the horizontal scrollbar when the vertical scrollbar was visible (when resizing the window). However, having just tested this on a couple of mobile browsers (as appears to be the target of these tests), I do not get the horizontal scrollbars in any of the tests above. As you suggest, on mobile Chrome (as with other mobile browsers), the very thin scrollbar appears on top of the content so does not affect the content width. (?)

Comment: @w3d yh i have had issues with this before but it was always on desktop browsers i believe there are some bug reports regarding scroll bars affecting the page widths but i do not believe there is a standard for this yet?

Comment: @w3d I'm also resizing my browser window to test and there appers the `horizontal scrollbar`. The real question is why can't use the minimal width possible when the `vertical scrollbar` present?

Comment: For some reason I can't duplicate your issue (on phone or desktop), and this may be a silly recommendation... but could it be that your padding:0 10px is adding a bit to the width, thus forcing the overflow?

Comment: @deebs check the [first jsbin](http://jsbin.com/veracelawo/1/edit?output) on your PC, an start reducing the width and you'll see that a `vertical scrollbar` will appear. As for padding, I'm using `box-sizing: border-box;` so that shouldn't be a problem.

Answer (score 5):

## Bootstrap Media Querys

**Setting media query**

Bootstrap supports four media sizes:

Phones < 768px (8 inch)

Tablets ≥ 768px

Desktops ≥ 992px (10.33 inch)

Desktops ≥ 1200px (12.5 inch)

**These are not fixed sizes!**

If you have a ***screen*** that has a min-width of 768px the media query should trigger.
**However setting a container to 768px will almost allways make that screen overflow**

First of all the `body` element of all modern browser does have a margin to it.
example: Webkit browsers: `body {margin: 8px;}` so if your element of 768px and a margin-top of 8 and margin-bottom of 8 you get: `784px`
so your screen is 768px (or less) and your content is 784px this will make it overflow (as it should). **That said bootstrap sets: `body {margin:0;}`**

An other example would be border. Border adds size to your element unless `box-sizing` isn't default. While outline sets the border inside your element.

> Did the guys from bootstrap did that on purpose, because of the possibily that there can be the presence of `vertical scrollbar` ?

There is a possibility of that but i would think they set it because there is a bunch of css property's that affect size, so they gave a *margin of error* so to speak to avoid strange behavior like a horizontal scroll bar popping up.

> Question: Why can't I use the minimal possible width in the media query when the vertical scrollbar is present?

You can use it: [Fiddle!](http://jsfiddle.net/poi33/x36y88gt/)
Just Remember that some browsers will render it with a certain width.

Comment: I used `body{margin:0}` and `box-sizing: border-box` in all my jsbins and it stills trigger the `horizontal scrollbar` when using the minimal possible width in media querys. I'm wondering why is _"However setting a container to 768px will almost allways make that screen overflow"_ happening?

Comment: Vucko did you read my answer? In desktop browsers the horizontal scrollbar can affect the width. And there are many propertys that affect the size of an element and if you just increase your content with 1px it wil overflow.

Comment: I agree with all that you said, but you didn't give any solution. If you inspect the jsbins, you'll see that there's nothing that can effect the width. How can I use the **minimal possible width** in my `media querys` if there is a _vertical scrollbar_ present? I don't want to use `@media (min-width: some_width - (scrollbar_width)){...}` in my `media querys`.

Comment: ahhh i see!! If you want to use your min-width `media querys` you have to make sure your container does not trigger the overflow. In other words keep the content width of your elements **lower** (not equal) to the media query your useing or scale the content to the view port (like 50vw or 50vh)

Comment: But the container doesn't trigger the overflow - the `vertical scrollbar` does. As for `viewport units`, there're [buggy](http://caniuse.com/#feat=viewport-units).

Comment: Wel your persistent: here is an article discussing the problem: http://www.sitepoint.com/rwd-scrollbars-is-chrome-better/ and an in-depth discussion of  the different browsers support for scrollbars

Comment: Well, I may be persistent, but I just want to know how to solve that issue **without** reducing  the `minimal width` in my `media querys`. I've already seen that article - it's in my OP.

Comment: Can you edit your question then, because you have two question currently: **I keep getting a horizontal scrollbar and I don't understand why?** and that's because you container overflows so you get a scrollbar and: **Did the guys from bootstrap did that on purpose, because of the possibily that there can be the presence of vertical scrollbar?** and this is answered aswel.

Comment: There's only one main question for which I want come clarification - **"Question: Why can't I use the minimal possible width in the media query when the vertical scrollbar is present?"**

Comment: Here's your [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vucko/x36y88gt/1/), I've modified it a little. Notice when you resize the window that the `horizontal scrollbar` will appear. But if you use `height:100%` instead of `height:2000px` (forced height, on the `#pink` element), the `horizontal scrollbar` won't apper. And that's whats bodering me.

Comment: The horizontal scrollbar will not appear because: `pink { width:100%;)` The 100% is not including the vertical scrollbar.

Answer (score -1):

Checkout the fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/YameenYasin/as4Lmgas/1/

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body{
  margin: 0;  
}

div {
  padding-right: 15px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  background: blue;
  height:auto;
  min-height:300px; // For testing purpose only
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  div {
    width: 750px;
    background: silver;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 992px) {
  div {
    width: 970px;
    background: yellow;
  }
}
@media (min-width: 1200px) {
  div {
    width: 1170px;
    background: red;
  }
}



<div></div>
```